# Ackermann function causes Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, recursion

Within React library I am writing an algorithm program which calculates the Ackermann function.

For some input like `n=4`, `m=1` I'm getting an

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Need some help to avoid this error.

```
ackermannCalc(n, m) {
        while (n !== 0) {
            if(m === 0){
                m = 1;
            } else {
                m = this.ackermannCalc(n, m - 1);
            }
            n = n - 1;
        }
        return m + 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see that this has any relation to React or React Router, so I removed the tags. As for the Ackermann function, Wikipedia says "Its value grows rapidly, even for small inputs. For example, A(4, 2) is an integer of 19,729 decimal digits".

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks for your editing. Even with wikipedia recursive defintion, i'm getting the same error

Comment: My first comment wasn't accurate. See the update--you can expect it to blow up the call stack even if correct.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for clarifacation, but how should i fix this propblem

Comment: Well, did you try doing it iteratively?

Comment: Just writing it iteratively is probably not enough because JS can't handle 19,729 digits. You can also use a big integer library, but basically, I wouldn't necessarily say there's any problem to be fixed--this is just a characteristic of the Ackermann function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ggorlen all what i'm trying to do is that user's input should be validated

Comment: @Ryu, looking at the Ackermann table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values, I would say that your efforts are somewhat futile.  First I've heard of the Ackermann function, and looking at ackermannCalc, `m` is incremented at most by +1 per iteration.  So, execution of something as simple looking as A(4,2) will be at least 2**65536 - 3 math operations(!), a ginormous number (as noted by ggorlen).  Even if a computer could perform a trillion operations per second and started when the big bang occurred, it would be no where near finishing!